# Click on the expand button I want to scroll down the page in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am creating the view programmatically and use the grid and added the child in the grid. In my view I am using the expanded and 
collapsed icon which is display the inner information.  When I click on the expanded button those are in bottom . In that situation
view is not scrolling down automatically.
I want to click on the expand button if they are present bottom in the device then automatically scroll down the view.

```
   <StackLayout x:Name=“stacklayout >                       
    <ScrollView Orientation="Vertical">          
    <Grid x:Name=“grid">         
    </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
</StackLayout>
```

I am adding the data in the grid from the code behind file.

Comment: Have you tried the `scrollView.ScrollToAsync(element)` method?

Comment: yes I tried this method but I am not but I am not able to find the exactly row element where I want to scroll down. Like I like on the top element then I dont want to scroll but if i like in the bottom point then I want to scroll down.